# Android clean architecture implement refresh token

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, clean-architecture

I have an application that is implemented with **clean architecture** with **MVVM** pattern. In this app we need a **refresh token request** that is needed in all the app features. When a refresh token is success then call the last request again. What is the best way to implement this?

I have two idea:

1 - Implement it in every feature and use it. So if I have three features in my app I will implement it three time.

2 - Implemented globally

I know the first idea but I can't figure out how to do the second one which I think is better.

I use retrofit for networking . The structure is : data , domain , presentation .

Comment: Which HTTP library are you using?

Comment: @HåkonSchia sorry. I updated my question. if you need any detail just tell me.

Answer (score 2):

With Retrofit you can create a custom `Authenticator` which will trigger when a request was denied because of an authentication error (typically 401, the documentation for the `Authenticator` interface explains more). In your authenticator you can retrieve a new token and automatically create a new request with the new token.

An authenticator will be something like:

```
class Authenticator : okhttp3.Authenticator {
    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
        // Make your network request to retrieve a new token
        val newToken = ...

        // Check if a new token was retrieved
        val retrievedNewToken: Boolean = true

        return if (retrievedNewToken) {
            response.request().newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "token-value-here")
                .build()
        } else {
            // Couldn't get new token, abort the request
            null
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in your OkHttpClient:

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .authenticator(Authenticator())
    .build()
```

This is a fairly general answer as I can't provide any specific way of doing it since I don't know the rest of your code, but that's the gist of it. Something to be aware of is that you might need to handle if a new token request is already happening, as it will potentially make multiple requests for a new token if you make several requests right after each other that all are denied.

Comment: Thanks . this might help. but I'm using clean arch. you think this is not against the oop rule?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. As I said, you'll have to decide how the actual implementation is if you want to use this approach, so you'll have to make it fit in a proper way for your code